# JSON value type casting

Tags: javascript, json, api, express, casting

This field value is a number but i am getting output as a string.

1. Do i typecast it? how do i do that?
2. I tried doing a parseInt but that doesnt work either, am i using it wrong?

Code:

```
    app.get("/api/timestamp/:date", function(req, res) {
      let dateString = req.params.date
      ...
      //This unix part here!
      if (dateString == 1451001600000) {
        res.json({ unix: 1451001600000, utc: "Fri, 25 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT"});
    }
});
```

My o/p:

```
{
unix: "1451001600000",
utc: "Fri, 25 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT"
}
```

Expected o/p :

```
{
unix: 1451001600000,
utc: "Fri, 25 Dec 2015 00:00:00 GMT"
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your output and expected output as text, rather than as links to pictures of text.

Comment: You use `parseInt` to create `dateInteger`, then use `dateString`, which is a string, as the value of `unix`. Use `dateInteger` if you want the parsed integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine with the casting and inputs for Date.

Try adding a `return` statement inside the first `if` after the res.json line. Otherwise line 9 will also be run for this case and the response is overwritten later on.

```js
if (/\d{5,}/.test(dateString)) {
    let dateInteger = parseInt(dateString);
    res.json({ unix: dateString, utc: new Date(dateInteger).toUTCString() });
    return;
}
```

After your recent edit I noticed you want a number for the unix property, so cast this one with `Number()` or use the `dateInteger`:

```
res.json({ unix: Number(dateString), utc: new Date(dateInteger).toUTCString() });
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help :) <3